# Copy values from 1 sheet and set values to last row of another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this has been done before, but I'm struggling to get mine working, I want to copy all data from sheet 'Templates' to 'History' sheet.

I want to send the values in a new row at the bottom of history sheet.

Here is my working code, I just need to change where the values are set.

```
var sheetTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Template');
var sheetHistory = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('History');

var getRange = sheetTemplate.getDataRange();
var DataCopied = SRange.getValues();

sheetHistory.getRange("a2:F7").setValues(DataCopied);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) methods, this will return the corresponding values in which data is present in a two-dimensional array, so when you copy the values to the new sheet with [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) you need to take into account the dimensions of the data retrieved so they match, you need to:

1. Get the last available row of the History Sheet with [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)
2. Get the "height" of the `DataCopied` Array (number of rows) with `DataCopied.length`
3. Get the "width" of the `DataCopied` Array (number of columns) `DataCopied[0].length`.
4. Get the range of that dimensions with [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns).
5. Set the values of the `DataCopied` with [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Your code should look like this:

```
function myFunction(){
  var sheetTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Template');
  var sheetHistory = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('History');

  var getRange = sheetTemplate.getDataRange();
  var DataCopied = getRange.getValues();

  // I defined the variables for better understanding      
  var startRow = sheetHistory.getLastRow()+1; // +1 because remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0].
  var startColumn = 1;
  var numRows = DataCopied.length;
  var numColumns = DataCopied[0].length;
  sheetHistory.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValues(DataCopied);

}
```